# title of a colored box

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, color, boxes

In an another post, [beamer style text box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74126/beamer-style-text-box/74127?noredirect=1#comment266795_74127), I've seen a box that I'm interested in making it. However, I would like to use it in a book, and I would like **before** the title to write: Definition (or Example) and then the number of the chapter and at the end the title.

For example: Definition 2.1:Good (when I'm on the second chapter, I'm giving the first definition here of the good)

What would be the code?

Also how could we add a list of definitions after the table of contents?

Comment: Have you read the manuals for the packages mdframed and tcolorbox?

Comment: You can combine the answer in the post you linked with the tips about making your own "list of...whatever" given [here](http://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new list of definitions was created using the LaTeX's kernel `\@starttoc` and it behaves in the same way as the standard LoF and LoT, but uses a file with extension `.ldf`. The boxes were defined using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exa}[chapter]
\counterwithin{exa}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listdefinitionname{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listdefinitionname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listdefinitionname}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listdefinitionname}%
    \@starttoc{ldf}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=green!40!black,
outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=green!40!black,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40!black,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}

\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}

\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\stepcounter{exa}%
    \addcontentsline{ldf}{figure}{#1}%
    \begin{exa}[frametitle=Definition~\theexa: #1]}
  {\end{exa}}

\begin{document}

\listofdefinitions

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{example}{The Title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}\par\bigskip

\begin{example}{Another Title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

An image of the new list of definitions:

[image]

An image of the look of the framed definitions:

[image]

The style and settings can be reused to define similar environments and lists:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exa}[chapter]
\newcounter{defi}[chapter]
\counterwithin{exa}{chapter}
\counterwithin{defi}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listdefinitionname{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listdefinitionname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listdefinitionname}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listdefinitionname}%
    \@starttoc{ldf}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listexamplename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listexamplename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listexamplename}%
    \@starttoc{lex}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=green!40!black,
outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=green!40!black,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40!black,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}

\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}
\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{defi}

\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\stepcounter{exa}%
    \addcontentsline{lex}{figure}{#1}%
    \begin{exa}[frametitle=Example~\theexa: #1]}
  {\end{exa}}

\newenvironment{definition}[1]
  {\stepcounter{defi}%
    \addcontentsline{ldf}{figure}{#1}%
    \begin{defi}[frametitle=Example~\thedefi: #1]}
  {\end{defi}}

\begin{document}

\listofdefinitions
\listofexamples

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{example}{The title of an example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}\par\bigskip

\begin{definition}{The title of a definition}
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I would like to have another box entitled as Example, what should I change in the code?

Comment: @giannis please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

A solution with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (exploiting [Formatting new list of definitions with tocloft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/formatting-new-list-of-definitions-with-tocloft#43312) for the new table of contents):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{good}
\setcounter{good}{0}

\newcommand{\listgoodname}{List of Goods}
\newlistof{goods}{good}{\listgoodname}

\newenvironment{good}[1]{
\stepcounter{good}
\addcontentsline{good}{figure}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thegood}#1}\par%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,title={Definition \thechapter.\thegood\space #1}]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\makeatletter
\preto\chapter{\addtocontents{good}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofgoods

\chapter{One}

\chapter{Two}
\section{First}

\begin{good}{A nice heading}
\lipsum[2]
\end{good}

\begin{good}{Good}
\lipsum[2]
\end{good}

\begin{good}{Good again}

\end{good}

\end{document}
```

The results (index):

[image]

and boxes:

[image]

Comment: If the whole passage of my box doesn't fit in a whole page, how can I manage to make it continue to the next page?

Comment: @giannis: For breakability you should modify the solution by `\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}` and add to the tcolorbox the options `breakable` (this will break the boxes but keep the partial boxes closed) or `enhanced,breakable` (this will break the boxes with opened borders).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I used the mdframed package, is it possible also in that package to break the box?

Comment: @giannis: with mdframed you're saved, since it automatically handles breaks: it is also stated in the abstract of the documentation.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I've read it, but in my document it doesn't breaks automatically. For the record I've used the code above (not yours-above that).

Comment: @giannis: The good news is that both `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` can be used for your purpose. `mdframed` uses breakable boxes as default and with `tcolorbox` you can switch breakability on and off. You should ask a new question with your code which does not work - it certainly can be fixed.