# Not breakable box in mdframed package

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, mdframed

In my previous post, [title of a colored box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119765/title-of-a-colored-box/119770?noredirect=1#comment267872_119770), I've tried the [first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119771/25572) answer I was given typing the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\author{}
\title{Μάθημα Επιλογής}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent \textit{Πρώτη Έκδοση, Ιούλιος 2013} % Printing/edition date
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\section{Δομή Τελικής Εξέτασης}
Το τελικό διαγώνισμα των Πανελλαδικών (ενίοτε και των ενδοσχολικών) εξετάσεων στο μάθημα αυτό απαρτίζεται από 4 ομάδες ασκήσεων. Αναλυτικότερα:


\begin{description}
\item[Ομάδα Α] Περιλαμβάνει:
\begin{itemize}
\item Πέντε προτάσεις του τύπου Σωστό - Λάθος, όπου η καθεμιά βαθμολογείται με τρεις (3) μονάδες.
\item Δύο ερωτήσεις πολλαπλής επιλογής, όπου η καθεμιά βαθμολογείται με πέντε (5) μονάδες.
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Β] Υπάρχει μια ερώτηση θεωρίας στην οποία καθένας μαθητής καλείται να αναπαράγει ένα απόσπασμα από το βιβλίο, το οποίο μπορεί να συνδέεται με διαγράμματα ή/και παραδείγματα. Πολλές φορές η ερώτηση εκτείνεται σε δύο σκέλη.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Γ] Υπάρχει μια άσκηση η οποία προέρχεται από 1 ή 2 κεφάλαια (συνδυαστική ή μη). Εμπειρικά η άσκηση είναι \textbf{συνήθως} από το πρώτο κεφάλαιο ή από το τρίτο και το τέταρτο.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Δ] Υπάρχει μια άσκηση με μεγάλο βαθμό συνδυαστικότητας όπου τα ζητούμενα συνήθως προέρχονται από τα κεφάλαια 5, 2, 4, 3.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\end{description}

\section{Εξεταστέα Ύλη}
Για τις εξετάσεις του σχολικού έτους 2012-2013: \\
\textit{Από το βιβλίο «Αρχές Οικονομικής Θεωρίας» της Γ΄ τάξης Γενικού Λυκείου των Λιανού Θ., Παπαβασιλείου Α. και Χατζηανδρέου Α. έκδοση 2012.}\\
\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 1:}} Βασικές Οικονομικές Έννοιες, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός των παραγράφων 6 και 13}.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 2:}} Η ζήτηση των αγαθών. \\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 3:}} Η παραγωγή της επιχείρησης και το κόστος, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός των παραγράφων 5, 6, 7, 8 και 9 που αναφέρονται στο κόστος παραγωγής}.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 4:}} Η προσφορά των αγαθών.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 5:}} Ο Προσδιορισμός των τιμών, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός της παραγράφου 6}.\\
\\
\textbf{Οι ερωτήσεις και οι ασκήσεις που αντιστοιχούν στα προαναφερόμενα κεφάλαια.}


\part{Σημειώσεις Μαθήματος \\ Θεωρία}
\chapter{Βασικές Οικονομικές Έννοιες}
\section{Αντικείμενο της Οικονομικής Επιστήμης}
Αντικείμενο της Οικονομικής Επιστήμης είναι τα τέσσερα επιμέρους οικονομικά προβλήματα\footnote{Βλ. παράλληλα κύριο οικονομικό πρόβλημα}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \underline{Τι} θα παραχθεί: αφορά το είδος και τις ποσότητες των προϊόντων που θα παραχθούν.
\item  \underline{Πώς θα παραχθεί}: αφορά τη μέθοδο και την τεχνολογία που θα χρησιμοποιηθεί στην παραγωγική διαδικασία.
\item  \underline{Πώς θα διανεμηθεί}: αφορά τα κριτήρια με τα οποία διανέμονται τα προϊόντα μεταξύ των ατόμων.
\item  \underline{Πώς αναπτύσσεται η οικονομία μιας κοινωνίας ώστε να αυξηθεί ο όγκος}\\ \underline{της παραγωγής}.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Οικονομία του Ροβινσώνα Κρούσου}
\textit{Να αναγνώσετε από το βιβλίο το αντίστοιχο κεφάλαιο (σελ. 9-10) και να κρατήσετε μόνο το νόημα. Συνήθως, ζητείται σε Σ-Λ.}

\section{Προϊόντα ή οικονομικά αγαθά}

\newcounter{mytheorem}[chapter]
\def\themytheorem{\arabic{mytheorem}}
\tcbset{
defstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=Blue!5!white,colframe=Blue!75!black},
}
\tcbmaketheorem{Definition}{Ορισμός}{defstyle}{mytheorem}{def}
\begin{Definition}{Αγαθό}{}
Είναι τα μέσα ικανοποίησης των αναγκών του ανθρώπου.\\ Διακρίνονται σε: \underline{ελεύθερα} (βρίσκονται ελεύθερα στη φύση και είναι απεριόριστα, π.χ. οξυγόνο) και \underline{οικονομικά} (αποτελέσματα παραγωγικής διαδικασίας, προϊόντα ή εμπορεύματα) 
\end{Definition}

\forestset{
  L1/.style={fill=SpringGreen,},
  L2/.style={fill=Apricot,edge={Apricot,line width=2pt}},
  L3/.style={fill=Goldenrod,edge={Goldenrod,line width=2pt}},
  L4/.style={fill=SkyBlue,edge={SkyBlue,line width=2pt}},
}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=10mm % level distance
    }
  [Αγαθά,L1
    [Οικονομικά,L2
        [Σύσταση,L3
            [Υλικά,L4][Άυλα*,L4]
        ]
        [Διάρκεια,L3
            [Διαρκή,L4][Καταναλωτά,L4]
        ]
        [Προορισμός,L3
            [Κεφαλαιουχικά,L4][Καταναλωτικά,L4]
        ] 
    ]
    [Ελεύθερα,L2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\captionof{figure}{Διάκριση των αγαθών}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\Pointinghand] Τα \textbf{άυλα} αγαθά είναι πάντα \textbf{καταναλωτά} και \textbf{καταναλωτικά}.
\item[\Pointinghand] Η οικονομική επιστήμη ασχολείται, σαφώς, μόνο με τα οικονομικά αγαθά.
\end{itemize}

\section{Η Αγορά}
\begin{Definition}{Αγορά (Στενή έννοια)}{}
Ο χώρος (γεωγραφικά) πραγματοποίησης αγοραπωλησιών, π.χ. εμπορικό κέντρο, λαϊκή αγορά κλπ.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{Αγορά (Ευρεία έννοια)}{}
Ο μηχανισμός επικοινωνίας αγοραστών και πωλητών για την πραγματοποίηση συναλλαγών που περιλαμβάνει μέσα όπως τηλέφωνο, φαξ, τύπος, \textlatin{internet} κλπ.
\end{Definition}

\section{Ανάγκες}
\begin{Definition}{Οικονομικές Ανάγκες}{}
Οικονομικές καλούνται οι ανάγκες που ικανοποιούνται με την κατανάλωση οικονομικών αγαθών.
\end{Definition}

\underline{Ιδιότητες Αναγκών}: 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Εξέλιξη***}: εξελίσσονται τα μέσα ικανοποίησης των αναγκών.
\item \textbf{Πολλαπλασιασμός***}: η συνεχής δημιουργία – αύξηση των ανα-γκών.
\item \textbf{Κορεσμός}: η βαθμιαία και προσωρινή ικανοποίηση των αναγκών
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{***Αίτια}:
\begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
\item τεχνολογία,
\item μίμηση,
\item συνήθεια,
\item διαφήμιση
\end{inparaenum}

\newcounter{THEtheorem}[chapter]
\def\THEtheorem{\arabic{THEtheorem}}
\tcbset{
theostyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
colback=Blue!25!yellow!5!white, colframe=Blue!25!yellow!90!white, coltitle=Blue!25!yellow!40!black},
}
\tcbmaketheorem{Theorem}{\Pointinghand}{theostyle}{THEtheorem}{theo}
\begin{Theorem}{Προσοχή!}{}
Οι ανάγκες στο σύνολό τους είναι ακόρεστες. \textbf{Ο κορεσμός αφορά τις ατομικές ανάγκες.} Οι συλλογικές ανάγκες είναι ακόρεστες!
\end{Theorem}

\section{Οι παραγωγικές δυνατότητες της οικονομίας}
\begin{Definition}{Παραγωγική Διαδικασία}{}
Είναι η διαδικασία μετασχηματισμού της ύλης μέσα από διαδοχικά στάδια έως ότου πάρει την τελική της μορφή.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{Συντελεστές παραγωγής}{}
Τα στοιχεία που συντελούν στην παραγωγική διαδικασία είναι: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item \underline{\textbf{Εργασία}}: η διανοητική και σωματική συμβολή του ανθρώπου. [+ ανθρώπινο κεφάλαιο: γνώσεις, εμπειρία, δεξιότητες]
\item \underline{\textbf{Φύση ή έδαφος}}: περιλαμβάνει όλους τους φυσικούς πόρους που συμβάλ-λουν στην παραγωγή (δάση, ποτάμια, κλπ)
\item \underline{\textbf{Κεφάλαιο}}: το σύνολο των κεφαλαιουχικών αγαθών (παραχθέντα μέσα παραγωγής) που παίρνουν μέρος στην παραγωγική διαδικασία.
\item \underline{\textbf{Επιχειρηματικότητα}}: η δραστηριότητα που αναλαμβάνει να συ-ντονίσει και να συνδυάσει τους άλλους τρεις συντελεστές στην παραγωγική διαδικασία ώστε να επιτευχθεί το μέγιστο κέρδος.
\end{enumerate}
\end{Definition}

\underline{\textit{ΣΗΜΕΙΩΣΗ:}} \textbf{«εν δυνάμει συντελεστές»} χαρακτηρίζονται οι συ-ντελεστές οι οποίοι θα μπορούσαν να συμβάλλουν στην παραγωγή αν χρησιμοποιούνταν.\\
\\
\underline{\textit{\textbf{Παρατηρήσεις:}}}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item οι παραγωγικοί συντελεστές βρίσκονται σε περιορισμένες ποσότητες δηλ. το χαρακτηριστικό τους είναι η ανεπάρκεια. 
\item οι συντελεστές μπορούν να χρησιμοποιηθούν εναλλακτικά μεταξύ τους, για την παραγωγή πολλών διαφορετικών αγαθών.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{Definition}{Η έννοια του κόστους}{}
Η παραγωγή ενός αγαθού δεσμεύει παραγωγικούς συντελεστές, οι οποίοι θα μπορούσαν, εναλλακτικά, να χρησιμοποιηθούν για την παραγωγή κάποιου άλλου ή άλλων αγαθών. Επομένως, οι ποσότητες των αγαθών που θα θυσιάζονται έτσι ώστε με τους συντελεστές που αποδεσμεύονται να παραχθεί κάποιο άλλο αγαθό αποτελούν το \textbf{πραγματικό} (ή εναλλακτικό) \textbf{κόστος} του αγαθού που παράγεται.
\end{Definition}

\section{Καμπύλη Παραγωγικών Δυνατοτήτων (ΚΠΔ)}

Οι παραγωγικές δυνατότητες της οικονομίας \underline{εξαρτώνται} από: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Τις ποσότητες των διαθέσιμων συντελεστών (\textbf{ποσοτικό} κριτήριο)
\item Τη δεδομένη διαθέσιμη τεχνολογία (\textbf{ποιοτικό} κριτήριο)
\end{enumerate}


\textbf{ΟΡΙΑ ΠΑΡΑΓΩΓΙΚΩΝ ΔΥΝΑΤΟΤΗΤΩΝ:} εννοούμε όλους τους μέγιστους (άριστους) συνδυασμούς προϊόντων που μπορεί να επιτύχει η οικονομία με την προϋπόθεση ότι: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Αξιοποιεί πλήρως όλους τους διαθέσιμους παραγωγικούς συντελεστές
\item Αξιοποιεί τη διαθέσιμη τεχνολογία (δεδομένη)
\item Υποθέτοντας, ότι παράγει δύο μόνο αγαθά.
\end{enumerate}

\textit{Για να αντιληφθούμε καλύτερα την έννοια της καμπύλης παραγωγικών δυνατοτήτων ας αξιοποιήσουμε το παράδειγμα\footnote{Βλέπε αναλυτικά λυμένες ασκήσεις σε επόμενες σελίδες.} 1.1.}

\begin{Definition}{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας}{}
\textbf{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας ή εναλλακτικό κόστος} ενός αγαθού Χ καλείται η ποσότητα που θυσιάζεται από κάποιο άλλο αγαθό Υ, έτσι ώστε να παραχθεί μια επιπλέον μονάδα του αγαθού Χ. Δηλαδή ισχύει ο τύπος: 
\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq:1}
\text{ΚΕ}_x=\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X} 
\end{eqnarray}
\end{Definition}


  \newcounter{exa}[chapter]
\counterwithin{exa}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=green!40!black,
outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlefont=\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=green!40!black,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40!black,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}
\makeatother
\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}

\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\stepcounter{exa}%
    \addcontentsline{ldf}{figure}{#1}%
    \begin{exa}[frametitle=Παράδειγμα~\theexa: #1]}
  {\end{exa}}


\begin{example}{Η ΚΠΔ} \label{1.1}
Αξιοποιούμε τα δεδομένα του παρακάτω πίνακα:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|cc|}
\hline
Συνδυασμός & Γάλα (τόνοι) & Φρούτα (τόνοι) & $\text{KE}_\text{φρούτων}$ & $\text{KE}_\text{γάλακτος}$ \\ 
\hline
A & 40 & 0 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 0.5 & 2 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
B & 30 & 20 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 1 & 1 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Γ & 20 & 30 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2 & 0.5 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Δ & 10 & 35 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2.5 & 0.4 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Ε & 0 & 39 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Η Καμπύλη Παραγωγικών Δυνατοτήτων που παίρνουμε βάσει του παραπάνω πίνακα είναι η ακόλουθη:

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 40,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 42, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = Φρούτα,
  ylabel = Γάλα
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,40) 
    (20,30)
    (30,20)
    (35,10)
(39,0)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,40);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:20,30);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs:30,20);
\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:35,10);
\coordinate (E) at (axis cs:39,0);
\end{axis}
\node[above right] at (A) {$A$};
\node[above right] at (B) {$\text{Β}$};
\node[above right] at (C) {$\text{Γ}$};
\node[above right] at (D) {$\text{Δ}$};
\node[above right] at (E) {$\text{Ε}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Η ΚΠΔ του παραδείγματος 1.1.}
\end{center}

Δεδομένου του ορισμού που δόθηκε προηγουμένως σχετικά με το κόστος Ευκαιρίας, υπολογίζουμε ακολούθως:\\

\textbf{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας Φρούτων}
\begin{align}
~\ref{eq:1} \Rightarrow \text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Α} \rightarrow \text{Β}}}& =\frac{\Delta \text{γαλακτ}}{\Delta \text{φρουτ}}=\frac{40-30}{20-0}=0.5 \text{ τόνοι γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Β} \rightarrow \text{Γ}}}& =\frac{30-20}{30-20}=1 \text{ τόνος γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Γ} \rightarrow \text{Δ}}}& =\frac{20-10}{35-30}=2 \text{ τόνοι γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Δ} \rightarrow \text{Ε}}}& =\frac{10-0}{39-35}=2,5 \text{ τόνοι γάλακτος} \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

The problem which I'm dealing concerns the box, which **doesn't** break at the end of the page.

Comment: Why all those consecutive `eqnarray` environments? Why `eqnarray`, in the first place?

Comment: what should I use instead?

Comment: The environments provided by `amsmath`. Also, please complete your snippet to a *complete* document.

Comment: After supplementing the necessary packages, I get a break before **Κόστος Ευκαιρίας Φρούτων**

Comment: I can confirm egreg's result. After adding `\usepackage{chngcntr,amsmath,pgfplots,caption}`, a
 page break occurs before  Κόστος Ευκαιρίας Φρούτων.

Comment: @giannis Perhaps you are using an outdated version of some package(s)?

Comment: @egreg What kind of packages should I add?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've included them, but still the problem exists

Comment: @giannis You didn't try the example, did you? At least `pgfplots`, `amsmath`, `chngcntr` and one between `caption` or `capt-of` are missing.

Comment: I'm going to try an update, even though it's been only 3 months that I've updated my packages.

Comment: @giannis: Does it work now. I  uploaded a new version of mdframed one week ago.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The problem still exists. The box doesn't break.

Comment: After adding the packages listed by @GonzaloMedina your example works well.

Comment: @giannis I edited your code and added the missing packages. Please, using the exact same code that appears in your question (after my edit), are you still getting the mnetioned problem?

Comment: When I create a new document with the code above it works. when I use it in my already existed document, it doesn't work.

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere and the code you posted is not enough to detect and diagnose the problem. Please compose a minimal example really illustrating the problem mentioned and edit your question, adding this new code (don't forget to post a complete compilable document).

Comment: I've editted all my complete compilable document. Could you find the mistake now?

Comment: It can't be our task to produce a minimal working example. First of all you should remove packages which are loaded twice.

Comment: Will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard work! Your document is not minimal, but al least it allowed to reproduce the problem. The problem comes from using `\captionof{figure}{...}` for the `forest` environment without extra precautions such as wrapping the whole thing in a `minipage`, for example, or in a any other appropriate environment. This is advised in the page 18 of the documentation of the caption package:

> Since `\captionof` uses the option `type` internally, the same
>   restrictions as for the `type` option apply here, so you should use
>   both `\captionof` and `\captionof*` only inside boxes or environments,
>   too.

Here's the code with the `forest` wrapped inside a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\author{}
\title{Μάθημα Επιλογής}
\date{\today}

\newcounter{exa}[chapter]
\counterwithin{exa}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=green!40!black,
outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlefont=\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=green!40!black,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40!black,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}
\makeatother
\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}

\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\stepcounter{exa}%
    \addcontentsline{ldf}{figure}{#1}%
    \begin{exa}[frametitle=Παράδειγμα~\theexa: #1]}
  {\end{exa}}

\newcounter{mytheorem}[chapter]
\def\themytheorem{\arabic{mytheorem}}
\tcbset{
defstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=Blue!5!white,colframe=Blue!75!black},
}
\tcbmaketheorem{Definition}{Ορισμός}{defstyle}{mytheorem}{def}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent \textit{Πρώτη Έκδοση, Ιούλιος 2013} % Printing/edition date
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\section{Δομή Τελικής Εξέτασης}
Το τελικό διαγώνισμα των Πανελλαδικών (ενίοτε και των ενδοσχολικών) εξετάσεων στο μάθημα αυτό απαρτίζεται από 4 ομάδες ασκήσεων. Αναλυτικότερα:


\begin{description}
\item[Ομάδα Α] Περιλαμβάνει:
\begin{itemize}
\item Πέντε προτάσεις του τύπου Σωστό - Λάθος, όπου η καθεμιά βαθμολογείται με τρεις (3) μονάδες.
\item Δύο ερωτήσεις πολλαπλής επιλογής, όπου η καθεμιά βαθμολογείται με πέντε (5) μονάδες.
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Β] Υπάρχει μια ερώτηση θεωρίας στην οποία καθένας μαθητής καλείται να αναπαράγει ένα απόσπασμα από το βιβλίο, το οποίο μπορεί να συνδέεται με διαγράμματα ή/και παραδείγματα. Πολλές φορές η ερώτηση εκτείνεται σε δύο σκέλη.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Γ] Υπάρχει μια άσκηση η οποία προέρχεται από 1 ή 2 κεφάλαια (συνδυαστική ή μη). Εμπειρικά η άσκηση είναι \textbf{συνήθως} από το πρώτο κεφάλαιο ή από το τρίτο και το τέταρτο.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\item[Ομάδα Δ] Υπάρχει μια άσκηση με μεγάλο βαθμό συνδυαστικότητας όπου τα ζητούμενα συνήθως προέρχονται από τα κεφάλαια 5, 2, 4, 3.\\
\textbf{Συνολικές μονάδες: 25}
\end{description}

\section{Εξεταστέα Ύλη}
Για τις εξετάσεις του σχολικού έτους 2012-2013: \\
\textit{Από το βιβλίο «Αρχές Οικονομικής Θεωρίας» της Γ΄ τάξης Γενικού Λυκείου των Λιανού Θ., Παπαβασιλείου Α. και Χατζηανδρέου Α. έκδοση 2012.}\\
\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 1:}} Βασικές Οικονομικές Έννοιες, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός των παραγράφων 6 και 13}.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 2:}} Η ζήτηση των αγαθών. \\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 3:}} Η παραγωγή της επιχείρησης και το κόστος, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός των παραγράφων 5, 6, 7, 8 και 9 που αναφέρονται στο κόστος παραγωγής}.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 4:}} Η προσφορά των αγαθών.\\
\textbf{\underline{Κεφάλαιο 5:}} Ο Προσδιορισμός των τιμών, \textcolor{Blue}{εκτός της παραγράφου 6}.\\
\\
\textbf{Οι ερωτήσεις και οι ασκήσεις που αντιστοιχούν στα προαναφερόμενα κεφάλαια.}


\part{Σημειώσεις Μαθήματος \\ Θεωρία}
\chapter{Βασικές Οικονομικές Έννοιες}
\section{Αντικείμενο της Οικονομικής Επιστήμης}
Αντικείμενο της Οικονομικής Επιστήμης είναι τα τέσσερα επιμέρους οικονομικά προβλήματα\footnote{Βλ. παράλληλα κύριο οικονομικό πρόβλημα}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \underline{Τι} θα παραχθεί: αφορά το είδος και τις ποσότητες των προϊόντων που θα παραχθούν.
\item  \underline{Πώς θα παραχθεί}: αφορά τη μέθοδο και την τεχνολογία που θα χρησιμοποιηθεί στην παραγωγική διαδικασία.
\item  \underline{Πώς θα διανεμηθεί}: αφορά τα κριτήρια με τα οποία διανέμονται τα προϊόντα μεταξύ των ατόμων.
\item  \underline{Πώς αναπτύσσεται η οικονομία μιας κοινωνίας ώστε να αυξηθεί ο όγκος}\\ \underline{της παραγωγής}.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Οικονομία του Ροβινσώνα Κρούσου}
\textit{Να αναγνώσετε από το βιβλίο το αντίστοιχο κεφάλαιο (σελ. 9-10) και να κρατήσετε μόνο το νόημα. Συνήθως, ζητείται σε Σ-Λ.}

\section{Προϊόντα ή οικονομικά αγαθά}

\begin{Definition}{Αγαθό}{}
Είναι τα μέσα ικανοποίησης των αναγκών του ανθρώπου.\\ Διακρίνονται σε: \underline{ελεύθερα} (βρίσκονται ελεύθερα στη φύση και είναι απεριόριστα, π.χ. οξυγόνο) και \underline{οικονομικά} (αποτελέσματα παραγωγικής διαδικασίας, προϊόντα ή εμπορεύματα) 
\end{Definition}
%

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\forestset{
  L1/.style={fill=SpringGreen,},
  L2/.style={fill=Apricot,edge={Apricot,line width=2pt}},
  L3/.style={fill=Goldenrod,edge={Goldenrod,line width=2pt}},
  L4/.style={fill=SkyBlue,edge={SkyBlue,line width=2pt}},
}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=10mm % level distance
    }
  [Αγαθά,L1
    [Οικονομικά,L2
        [Σύσταση,L3
            [Υλικά,L4][Άυλα*,L4]
        ]
        [Διάρκεια,L3
            [Διαρκή,L4][Καταναλωτά,L4]
        ]
        [Προορισμός,L3
            [Κεφαλαιουχικά,L4][Καταναλωτικά,L4]
        ] 
    ]
    [Ελεύθερα,L2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\captionof{figure}{Διάκριση των αγαθών}
\end{minipage}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\Pointinghand] Τα \textbf{άυλα} αγαθά είναι πάντα \textbf{καταναλωτά} και \textbf{καταναλωτικά}.
\item[\Pointinghand] Η οικονομική επιστήμη ασχολείται, σαφώς, μόνο με τα οικονομικά αγαθά.
\end{itemize}

\section{Η Αγορά}
\begin{Definition}{Αγορά (Στενή έννοια)}{}
Ο χώρος (γεωγραφικά) πραγματοποίησης αγοραπωλησιών, π.χ. εμπορικό κέντρο, λαϊκή αγορά κλπ.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{Αγορά (Ευρεία έννοια)}{}
Ο μηχανισμός επικοινωνίας αγοραστών και πωλητών για την πραγματοποίηση συναλλαγών που περιλαμβάνει μέσα όπως τηλέφωνο, φαξ, τύπος, \textlatin{internet} κλπ.
\end{Definition}

\section{Ανάγκες}
\begin{Definition}{Οικονομικές Ανάγκες}{}
Οικονομικές καλούνται οι ανάγκες που ικανοποιούνται με την κατανάλωση οικονομικών αγαθών.
\end{Definition}

\underline{Ιδιότητες Αναγκών}: 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Εξέλιξη***}: εξελίσσονται τα μέσα ικανοποίησης των αναγκών.
\item \textbf{Πολλαπλασιασμός***}: η συνεχής δημιουργία – αύξηση των ανα-γκών.
\item \textbf{Κορεσμός}: η βαθμιαία και προσωρινή ικανοποίηση των αναγκών
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{***Αίτια}:
\begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
\item τεχνολογία,
\item μίμηση,
\item συνήθεια,
\item διαφήμιση
\end{inparaenum}

\newcounter{THEtheorem}[chapter]
\def\THEtheorem{\arabic{THEtheorem}}
\tcbset{
theostyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
colback=Blue!25!yellow!5!white, colframe=Blue!25!yellow!90!white, coltitle=Blue!25!yellow!40!black},
}
\tcbmaketheorem{Theorem}{\Pointinghand}{theostyle}{THEtheorem}{theo}
\begin{Theorem}{Προσοχή!}{}
Οι ανάγκες στο σύνολό τους είναι ακόρεστες. \textbf{Ο κορεσμός αφορά τις ατομικές ανάγκες.} Οι συλλογικές ανάγκες είναι ακόρεστες!
\end{Theorem}

\section{Οι παραγωγικές δυνατότητες της οικονομίας}
\begin{Definition}{Παραγωγική Διαδικασία}{}
Είναι η διαδικασία μετασχηματισμού της ύλης μέσα από διαδοχικά στάδια έως ότου πάρει την τελική της μορφή.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}{Συντελεστές παραγωγής}{}
Τα στοιχεία που συντελούν στην παραγωγική διαδικασία είναι: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item \underline{\textbf{Εργασία}}: η διανοητική και σωματική συμβολή του ανθρώπου. [+ ανθρώπινο κεφάλαιο: γνώσεις, εμπειρία, δεξιότητες]
\item \underline{\textbf{Φύση ή έδαφος}}: περιλαμβάνει όλους τους φυσικούς πόρους που συμβάλ-λουν στην παραγωγή (δάση, ποτάμια, κλπ)
\item \underline{\textbf{Κεφάλαιο}}: το σύνολο των κεφαλαιουχικών αγαθών (παραχθέντα μέσα παραγωγής) που παίρνουν μέρος στην παραγωγική διαδικασία.
\item \underline{\textbf{Επιχειρηματικότητα}}: η δραστηριότητα που αναλαμβάνει να συ-ντονίσει και να συνδυάσει τους άλλους τρεις συντελεστές στην παραγωγική διαδικασία ώστε να επιτευχθεί το μέγιστο κέρδος.
\end{enumerate}
\end{Definition}

\underline{\textit{ΣΗΜΕΙΩΣΗ:}} \textbf{«εν δυνάμει συντελεστές»} χαρακτηρίζονται οι συ-ντελεστές οι οποίοι θα μπορούσαν να συμβάλλουν στην παραγωγή αν χρησιμοποιούνταν.\\
\\
\underline{\textit{\textbf{Παρατηρήσεις:}}}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item οι παραγωγικοί συντελεστές βρίσκονται σε περιορισμένες ποσότητες δηλ. το χαρακτηριστικό τους είναι η ανεπάρκεια. 
\item οι συντελεστές μπορούν να χρησιμοποιηθούν εναλλακτικά μεταξύ τους, για την παραγωγή πολλών διαφορετικών αγαθών.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{Definition}{Η έννοια του κόστους}{}
Η παραγωγή ενός αγαθού δεσμεύει παραγωγικούς συντελεστές, οι οποίοι θα μπορούσαν, εναλλακτικά, να χρησιμοποιηθούν για την παραγωγή κάποιου άλλου ή άλλων αγαθών. Επομένως, οι ποσότητες των αγαθών που θα θυσιάζονται έτσι ώστε με τους συντελεστές που αποδεσμεύονται να παραχθεί κάποιο άλλο αγαθό αποτελούν το \textbf{πραγματικό} (ή εναλλακτικό) \textbf{κόστος} του αγαθού που παράγεται.
\end{Definition}

\section{Καμπύλη Παραγωγικών Δυνατοτήτων (ΚΠΔ)}

Οι παραγωγικές δυνατότητες της οικονομίας \underline{εξαρτώνται} από: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Τις ποσότητες των διαθέσιμων συντελεστών (\textbf{ποσοτικό} κριτήριο)
\item Τη δεδομένη διαθέσιμη τεχνολογία (\textbf{ποιοτικό} κριτήριο)
\end{enumerate}


\textbf{ΟΡΙΑ ΠΑΡΑΓΩΓΙΚΩΝ ΔΥΝΑΤΟΤΗΤΩΝ:} εννοούμε όλους τους μέγιστους (άριστους) συνδυασμούς προϊόντων που μπορεί να επιτύχει η οικονομία με την προϋπόθεση ότι: 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Αξιοποιεί πλήρως όλους τους διαθέσιμους παραγωγικούς συντελεστές
\item Αξιοποιεί τη διαθέσιμη τεχνολογία (δεδομένη)
\item Υποθέτοντας, ότι παράγει δύο μόνο αγαθά.
\end{enumerate}

\textit{Για να αντιληφθούμε καλύτερα την έννοια της καμπύλης παραγωγικών δυνατοτήτων ας αξιοποιήσουμε το παράδειγμα\footnote{Βλέπε αναλυτικά λυμένες ασκήσεις σε επόμενες σελίδες.} 1.1.}

\begin{Definition}{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας}{}
\textbf{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας ή εναλλακτικό κόστος} ενός αγαθού Χ καλείται η ποσότητα που θυσιάζεται από κάποιο άλλο αγαθό Υ, έτσι ώστε να παραχθεί μια επιπλέον μονάδα του αγαθού Χ. Δηλαδή ισχύει ο τύπος: 
\begin{eqnarray} \label{eq:1}
\text{ΚΕ}_x=\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X} 
\end{eqnarray}
\end{Definition}



\begin{example}{Η ΚΠΔ} \label{1.1}
Αξιοποιούμε τα δεδομένα του παρακάτω πίνακα:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|cc|}
\hline
Συνδυασμός & Γάλα (τόνοι) & Φρούτα (τόνοι) & $\text{KE}_\text{φρούτων}$ & $\text{KE}_\text{γάλακτος}$ \\ 
\hline
A & 40 & 0 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 0.5 & 2 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
B & 30 & 20 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 1 & 1 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Γ & 20 & 30 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2 & 0.5 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Δ & 10 & 35 &  &  \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 2.5 & 0.4 \\ 
\cline{1-3}
Ε & 0 & 39 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Η Καμπύλη Παραγωγικών Δυνατοτήτων που παίρνουμε βάσει του παραπάνω πίνακα είναι η ακόλουθη:

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 40,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 42, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = Φρούτα,
  ylabel = Γάλα
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,40) 
    (20,30)
    (30,20)
    (35,10)
(39,0)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,40);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:20,30);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs:30,20);
\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:35,10);
\coordinate (E) at (axis cs:39,0);
\end{axis}
\node[above right] at (A) {$A$};
\node[above right] at (B) {$\text{Β}$};
\node[above right] at (C) {$\text{Γ}$};
\node[above right] at (D) {$\text{Δ}$};
\node[above right] at (E) {$\text{Ε}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Η ΚΠΔ του παραδείγματος 1.1.}
\end{center}

Δεδομένου του ορισμού που δόθηκε προηγουμένως σχετικά με το κόστος Ευκαιρίας, υπολογίζουμε ακολούθως:\par\bigskip

\textbf{Κόστος Ευκαιρίας Φρούτων}
\begin{align}
~\ref{eq:1} \Rightarrow \text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Α} \rightarrow \text{Β}}}& =\frac{\Delta \text{γαλακτ}}{\Delta \text{φρουτ}}=\frac{40-30}{20-0}=0.5 \text{ τόνοι γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Β} \rightarrow \text{Γ}}}& =\frac{30-20}{30-20}=1 \text{ τόνος γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Γ} \rightarrow \text{Δ}}}& =\frac{20-10}{35-30}=2 \text{ τόνοqι γάλακτος} \nonumber \\
\text{ΚΕ}_{\text{φρ}_{\text{Δ} \rightarrow \text{Ε}}}& =\frac{10-0}{39-35}=2,5 \text{ τόνοι γάλακτος} \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

#### Some additional remarks

1. The document as it is, produces lots of warnings about multiple defined labels, and `hyperref` warnings about using unvalid glyphs in some context; please review carefully those warnings and take the necessary measures to prevent them.
2. The definitions of environments and commands should be made in the preamble to facilitate possible modifications and adjustments; I moved some of the definitions from the body of the document to the preamble (the ones I quickly spotted); please review your document and make sure things that must go in the preamble are there.
3. The problematic box ends with a displayed `align` environment; this might produce (as large displayed expressions do) a page break too early or too late. Please read carefully the documentation for `amsmath` about `\displaybreak` and  `\allowdisplaybreaks`.
4. You are using `align` without alignment; `amsmath` provides other environments in case alignment is not required.
5. You are using `eqnrray` for displayed equations of a single line. `eqnarray` should *never* be used. For one-liners, you can use `\[...\]` or `equation*` (unnumbered) or `equation` (numbered). Again, read the `amsmath` documentation.
6. You are loading some packages twice; this is a potential source of errors. Please review your preamble to make sure each package is loaded just once with the options you need.

Comment: I'm really going to consider all of your comments. Thank you.