# customized table of content for examples

Tags: table-of-contents

I do have a customized examples environment, now I need a table of content for it, I don't know how is that possible. Here is my environment

```
\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\arabic{example}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
         linecolor=black,
         outerlinewidth=1pt,
         bottomline=true,
         leftline=false,rightline=false,
         skipabove=\baselineskip,
         skipbelow=\baselineskip,
         frametitle=\mbox{},
 }
 \newmdenv[%
        style=example,
        settings={\global\refstepcounter{example}},
        frametitlefont={\bfseries Exemple~\theexample\quad},
 ]{example}
```

thanks.

Comment: You're a member of TeX.SE for more than 2 years and have 324 rep and yet again a fragment of code? Your request is very easy with `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed` (which you're using, apparently), however. Perhaps it is possible with the `startcode` option, i.e. `startcode=\addcontentsline{exa}{section}{Title of the box}`, but this might get tedious

Comment: sorry but I didn't learned yet how to build environments and macros, and the majority of the example environment code, I piked it from here at TEX

Comment: Well, apart from some users most of us provide compilable documents as answers for good reasons, that anybody can make use of it, not meaning to be disrupted and reposted again

Comment: Here is a answer of mine doing what is requested with `tcolorbox`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276345/how-can-i-create-a-custom-directory-like-table-of-contents-e-g-list-of-exampl

Comment: Possible dupplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276345/120578 (it is not a flag but a question to the OP)

Comment: it is not a duplicate post because the environment used in this one is different from the other

Comment: @HindDev: It is no duplicate because you're using `mdframed`, but as long as you don't post a compilable document instead of fragments there will be not much help

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, ah! I see, it is because I have used your code in the link you gave to me, I found it more butiful